# An exception occurred during transition paint

Tags: codenameone

java.lang.NullPointerException occurred but the apps run normally.. is it a bug?

An exception occurred during transition paint this might be valid in case of a resize in the middle of a transition

```
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.setUrl(ConnectionRequest.java:1320)
    at com.codename1.io.Util.downloadUrlTo(Util.java:1202)
    at com.codename1.io.Util.downloadUrlToStorageInBackground(Util.java:1185)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage.fetch(URLImage.java:233)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage.getInternal(URLImage.java:264)
    at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getInternalImpl(EncodedImage.java:303)
    at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.drawImage(EncodedImage.java:491)
    at com.codename1.ui.Graphics.drawImage(Graphics.java:546)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.DefaultLookAndFeel.drawComponent(DefaultLookAndFeel.java:1113)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.DefaultLookAndFeel.drawLabel(DefaultLookAndFeel.java:381)
    at com.codename1.ui.Label.paint(Label.java:417)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.internalPaintImpl(Component.java:1282)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternalImpl(Component.java:1256)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:1231)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.paint(Container.java:1076)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.internalPaintImpl(Component.java:1282)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternalImpl(Component.java:1256)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:1231)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.paint(Container.java:1076)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.internalPaintImpl(Component.java:1282)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternalImpl(Component.java:1256)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:1231)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.paint(Container.java:1076)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.paint(Form.java:2934)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.internalPaintImpl(Component.java:1282)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.internalPaintImpl(Form.java:2944)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternalImpl(Component.java:1256)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:1231)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:1199)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintComponent(Component.java:1477)
    at com.codename1.ui.animations.CommonTransitions.paint(CommonTransitions.java:1157)
    at com.codename1.ui.animations.CommonTransitions.paint(CommonTransitions.java:1119)
    at com.codename1.ui.animations.CommonTransitions.paintSlideAtPosition(CommonTransitions.java:963)
    at com.codename1.ui.animations.CommonTransitions.paint(CommonTransitions.java:658)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.paintTransitionAnimation(Display.java:922)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1041)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:994)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Updated:

```
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.setUrl(ConnectionRequest.java:1320)
    at com.codename1.io.Util.downloadUrlTo(Util.java:1202)
    at com.codename1.io.Util.downloadUrlToStorageInBackground(Util.java:1185)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage.fetch(URLImage.java:233)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage.getInternal(URLImage.java:264)
    at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getInternalImpl(EncodedImage.java:303)
    at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.drawImage(EncodedImage.java:491)
    at com.codename1.ui.Graphics.drawImage(Graphics.java:546)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.DefaultLookAndFeel.drawComponent(DefaultLookAndFeel.java:1113)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.DefaultLookAndFeel.drawLabel(DefaultLookAndFeel.java:381)
    at com.codename1.ui.Label.paint(Label.java:417)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.internalPaintImpl(Component.java:1282)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternalImpl(Component.java:1256)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:1231)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.paint(Container.java:1076)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.internalPaintImpl(Component.java:1282)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternalImpl(Component.java:1256)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:1231)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.paint(Container.java:1076)
An exception occurred during transition paint this might be valid in case of a resize in the middle of a transition
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.internalPaintImpl(Component.java:1282)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternalImpl(Component.java:1256)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:1231)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.paint(Container.java:1076)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.paint(Form.java:2934)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.internalPaintImpl(Component.java:1282)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.internalPaintImpl(Form.java:2944)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternalImpl(Component.java:1256)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:1231)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintInternal(Component.java:1199)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.paintComponent(Component.java:1477)
    at com.codename1.ui.animations.CommonTransitions.paint(CommonTransitions.java:1157)
    at com.codename1.ui.animations.CommonTransitions.paint(CommonTransitions.java:1119)
    at com.codename1.ui.animations.CommonTransitions.paintSlideAtPosition(CommonTransitions.java:963)
    at com.codename1.ui.animations.CommonTransitions.paint(CommonTransitions.java:658)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.paintTransitionAnimation(Display.java:922)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1041)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:994)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Comment: The stack trace is partial, please post the full stack trace

Comment: that is all i get in the output... it doesnt point to any specific lines only the error is shown

Comment: Exception code might be mixed with the rest of your output, the top of the stack trace must start with the type of the exception so it might be higher up. We need that top section as its the most important part...

Comment: Updated the question hav a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your `URLImage` objects was created with a null URL.

We'll fix it so it throws the exception sooner and makes it more intuitive to discover which `URLImage` was at fault.